# Can you check what is stored in an X and Y coordinate on the screen in Assembly x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

The objective of my assembly project is to check if something has been printed in the location through a Randomizer built in function that will print a character that is given randomly on the screen. If something has been found in those coordinates, then the program should successfully print the next ASCII character that is found in that position.

There are many built-in functions being used from the Kip Irvine library.

There is a specific function called gotoxy that will go to the coordinate on the screen. While dumping the registers, I saw that the row and columns are stored in al and ah of eax. Is there a way to get the character stored in those coordinates by using al and ah?

Will I need to utilize esi to get the address of what is stored in those coordinates and then dereference it?

Comment: What operating system will the program be running under?

Comment: Running it on Visual Studio and Windows.

Comment: Yes there is.  Since you're talking about Irvine, I'm assuming your doing DOS programming.  Look up the "BIOS Interrupt List" in Google and look for an interrupt that reads values on the screen.  Either that or look at the proper offset from `$B800` yourself.

Comment: It looks like int 08h will do exactly what I need! is there a way to store what is found there into a register?